# How to make a Facebook Canvas Application without SSL Certificate?

Tags: facebook, ssl, https

I am trying to create a Facebook Canvas Application, and am now required to proved an HTTPS URL for my canvas page.  They must have just recently made this a requirement.

The price of an SSL certificate is pretty absurd, some costing over $1000 a year.  I am not rich, and simply can't afford it.

I have heard I can use a self signed certificate, will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Self signed certificate will only work for yourself during development - but SSL certificates are not that expensive, check this out: http://www.startssl.com/ - Not sure where you saw $1000/year, maybe you just did a typo? $100 would seem like a reasonable price.